# Route not working except the main url, Not Found HTTP Exception laravel-5

Tags: php, laravel, url, root

I got this error

[image: NotFoundHttpException]

Apart from the URL ("/"),  nothing is working. I run the following commands:

- `composer dump-autoload`
- `php artisan clear-compiled`
- `php artisan route:clear`

And when I display all route with `artisan route:list`, I got all the roots in my root file.

Example of Route in my route file:

[image: Example of routes in route file]

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan route:clear` ?

Comment: tried one of your route as `http://yourdomain/index.php/home`, let me know if it is working ?

Comment: add view path folder image as well

Comment: we need some more code to decide what's wrong .

Comment: @Vikash : yes I tried this command, but the same probleme

Comment: Did you try to run any of your route after index.php ?

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod rewrite in apache.
If on linux use

```
    sudo a2enmod rewrite
```